# Does Kunneth formula work for sheaf cohomology with coefficients on the tangent bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

I want to calculate $H^1(X, TX)$, where $X=\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}P^2$ and $TX$ is the sheaf of holomorphic sections of the tangent bundle of $X$.  I do not know if the Kunneth formula can be used in this situation. Would there be a simple way to compute this?

Comment: What cohomology are you talking about? In any case, the tangent bundle of a product is the direct sum of two bundles, each the pullback of the tangent bundle of one of the factors along the corresponding projection. can you use that?

Comment: It is sheaf cohomology. Maybe I can use this fact, I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are still interested, but just in case I'll complete the hint by Mariano. You don't need the Kunneth formula. We have $T(X_1 \times X_2) \cong \pi_1^*TX_1 \oplus \pi_2^*TX_2$ where $\pi_i : X \to X_i$ are the projections.

Now $TX_1 = T\Bbb C$ is the trivial line bundle so does not contribute to $H^1$ and we get $H^1(X,TX) = H^1(X, \pi_2^*T\Bbb P^2) \overset{\pi_2 \text{ is flat }}{=} H^1(\Bbb P^2,T\Bbb P^2) = 0$ where the last equality can be easily verified using the Euler exact sequence.